# Iterating through json array with appended json string in android after json as response from url using volley

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley, android-json

Hi i am trying to iterate through a json string that looks like this:

```
{
  "vendor":[ 
             {
               "vendor_name":"Tapan Moharana",
               "vendor_description":"",
               "vendor_slug":"tapan",
               "vendor_logo":null,
               "contact_number":null
             }
           ],
           "products":
              {
                "25": 
                  {
                    "name":"Massage",
                    "price":"5000.0000",
                    "image":"http:\/\/carrottech.com\/lcart\/media\/catalog\/product\/cache\/1\/image\/150x\/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95\/2\/9\/29660571-beauty-spa-woman-portrait-beautiful-girl-touching-her-face.jpg"
                  },
                "26":
                  {
                    "name":"Chicken Chilly",
                    "price":"234.0000",
                    "image":"http:\/\/carrottech.com\/lcart\/media\/catalog\/product\/cache\/1\/image\/150x\/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95\/c\/h\/cheicken.jpg"
                  },
                "27":
                 {
                    "name":"Chicken Biryani",
                    "price":"500.0000",
                    "image":"http:\/\/carrottech.com\/lcart\/media\/catalog\/product\/cache\/1\/image\/150x\/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95\/placeholder\/default\/image_1.jpg"
                  }
              }
   }
```

here is a better view of the json string:

[image]

I am iterating through the vendor array of this json string using this code:

```
JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(response);
JSONArray children = jsono.getJSONArray("vendor");
for (int i = 0; i <children.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonData = children.getJSONObject(i);
    System.out.print(jsonData.getString("vendor_name") + "<----");
    //  String vendorThumbNailURL=jsonData.getString("")
    //jvendorImageURL.setImageUrl(local, mImageLoader);
    vendorLogo=vendorLogo+jsonData.getString("vendor_logo").trim();
    jvendorImageURL.setImageUrl(vendorLogo, mImageLoader);
    jvendorName.setText(jsonData.getString("vendor_name"));
    jvendorAbout.setText(jsonData.getString("vendor_description"));
    jvendorContact.setText(jsonData.getString("contact_number"));
}
```

but I dont know how to get data from the "products" object please help me how do i set my json objects to iterate through "products"

when i try to change the format of the array so that both products and vendor are a separate json array i still get the above json format..

this is what i am doing

```
$resp_array['vendor'] = $info;
$resp_array['products'] = $vendorProductsInfo;
$resp_array = json_encode($resp_array);
    print_r($resp_array);
```

please help me with this

MODIFIED QUESTION:

I have modified my web response like this:

```
[{"entity_id":24,"product_name":"Burger","product_image_url":"\/b\/u\/burger_large.jpg","price":"234.0000","category_id":59},{"entity_id":27,"product_name":"Chicken Biryani","product_image_url":"\/b\/i\/biryani.jpg","price":"500.0000","category_id":59},{"entity_id":31,"product_name":"Pizza","product_image_url":"\/p\/i\/pizza_png7143_1.png","price":"125.0000","category_id":59}]
```

and the code:

```
 JSONArray children = jsono.getJSONArray("vendor");
                        for (int i = 0; i <children.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonData = children.getJSONObject(i);
                            System.out.print(jsonData.getString("vendor_name") + "<----");
                          //  String vendorThumbNailURL=jsonData.getString("")
                            //jvendorImageURL.setImageUrl(local, mImageLoader);
                            vendorLogo=vendorLogo+jsonData.getString("vendor_logo").trim();
                            jvendorImageURL.setImageUrl(vendorLogo, mImageLoader);
                            jvendorName.setText(jsonData.getString("vendor_name"));
                            jvendorAbout.setText(jsonData.getString("vendor_description"));
                            jvendorContact.setText(jsonData.getString("contact_number"));
                            System.out.print(jsonData.getString("products") + "<----");
                        }
                        JSONObject jsono1 = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONArray childrenProducts = jsono1.getJSONArray("products");
                        for(int i=0;i<childrenProducts.length();i++){
                            JSONObject jsonData = childrenProducts.getJSONObject(i);
                            System.out.print(jsonData.getString("name") + "<----dd");
                        }
```

but still the products part is not working... please help

Comment: Hi. If you feel the solution provided by me is right, please mark it complete. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the working solution: Using GOOGLE GSON (Open source jar)

```
import java.io.IOException;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;



     public class JsonToJava {

            public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
                try{
                    String json = "<YOUR_JSON>";
                    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
                    VendorInfo vInfo = gson.fromJson(json, VendorInfo.class);       
                    System.out.println(vInfo.getVendorName());              
                } catch(Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

Create classes for Vendor and Product

```
public class Vendor {
    public String vendor_name;
    public String vendor_description;
    public String vendor_slug;
    public String vendor_logo;
    public String contact_number;

    public String getName() {
        return vendor_name;
    }
}

public class Product {
    public String name;
    public long price;
    public String image;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

VendorInfo is the JSON object form:

```
import java.util.Map;

public class VendorInfo {
    public Vendor[] vendor;
    public Map<Integer, Product> products;

    public String getVendorName() {
        return vendor[0].getName();
    }
    public Product getProduct() {
        System.out.println(products.size());
        return products.get(25);
    }
}
```

You can add your getters for Vendor, Product and VendorInfo. You are done! You will get all the data.

Output of JsonToJava:

```
Tapan Moharana
```

Answer (score 1):

To get your *products* data , you need to use `Iterator`

```
   JSONObject jProducts = jsonObject
            .optJSONObject("products");
    try {
        if (jProducts
                .length() > 0) {
            Iterator<String> p_keys = jProducts
                    .keys();
            while (p_keys
                    .hasNext()) {
                String keyProduct = p_keys
                        .next();
                JSONObject jP = jProducts
                        .optJSONObject(keyProduct);

                if (jP != null) {
                    Log.e("Products",
                            jP.toString());
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) { // TODO:
        // handle
        // exception
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try with this

```
JSONObject jsono = null;
    try {
        jsono = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONObject productObject = jsono.getJSONObject("products");
        Iterator<String> keys = productObject.keys();

        while (keys.hasNext())
        {
            // get the key
            String key = keys.next();

            // get the value
            JSONObject value = productObject.getJSONObject(key);

            //get seprate objects
            String name = value.getString("name");
            String image = value.getString("image");
            Log.i(TAG,name+"-"+image);

         }
        } 
       catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: It isnt working.. it is considering productObject as one whole string not each part of it as object..                                                       JSONObject productChildren = jsono.getJSONObject("products");
                        for(int i=0;i<productChildren.length();i++){
                            JSONObject post = productChildren.getJSONObject(i);//Getting type conversion warning here
                            System.out.println(post.getString("name")+"<<<---");
                        }

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
JSONObject productObject = jsono.getJSONObject("products");

JSONObject json_25 = productObject getJSONObject("25");
String name_25= json_25.getString("name");
String price_25= json_25.getString("price");
String image_25= json_25.getString("image");

JSONObject json_26 = productObject getJSONObject("26");
String name_26= json_26.getString("name");
String price_26= json_26.getString("price");
String image_26= json_26.getString("image");

JSONObject json_27 = productObject getJSONObject("27");
String name_27= json_27.getString("name");
String price_27= json_27.getString("price");
String image_27= json_27.getString("image");
```

Comment: Bro this is a static implementation i need to iterate it using a while or for loop because the data that ill be getting from url will not always be of the same size it.

Comment: But the Response which you getting is in wrong format. Instead of 25,26,27 there should be json array

Comment: yes i am trying to put it in an array in my webservice

Comment: If it will be in array then you can parse projects like vendor.